# Compiling to ES6?

Tags: haxe

How would I compile

```
export default User
import socket from "./socket"
```

this ES6 javascript function with haxe?

```
import socket from "./socket"
let User = {
    init(socket, element) {
        if (!element) {
            return
        }
        let userId = element.getAttribute("data-id")
        userId= Math.random()
        socket.connect()
        this.onReady(userId, socket)
    }
}
export default User
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had the same need a while ago, in order to integrate with Ember 2.0/Ember CLI. I didn't find a way with pure Haxe, the only alternative is to either:

1) Build a custom js generator - clunky because you lose the goodies of the built-in js generator since there's **no** granular control over what features you use - it's all or nothing - i.e you can't only change the output of a certain expression/type in the AST, and you can't reference the built-in generator and delegate to it when needed.

2) A pre-processor that parses the `hx` file, removes the ES6 code, compiles the file, and adds the ES6 code back, clunky as well, but might work.

3) Hack the OCAML code for the compiler and add some kind of class-level metadata tag, something like `@:ESImport("import {foo} from bar")`, `@:ESExport("export default foo")`. This could also be done with #1 (custom js gen), but by modifying the OCaml code, you get to keep the built-in js gen.

I've given up on integrating Haxe code with ES6 for now, I wish Haxe had better build-in support for ES6 (i.e an ES2016 generator) or more granular hooks for the JS Custom generator API.

As a reference, here's my message to the Haxe mailing list, about this very issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/jSTkkaNgfB8.

Comment: __UPDATE:__ At the time of this writing, there is a custom haxejs generator that has support for ES6 classes. Check https://github.com/kevinresol/hxgenjs.

Answer (score 0):

As of [4.0.0-rc.2](https://haxe.org/download/version/4.0.0-rc.2/), Haxe now supports generation of ES6 classes with the `-D je-es=6` flag.

With that, this example...

```haxe
class Main {
    static function main() {
        trace("Hello World");
    }
}
```

...produces the following JavaScript code:

```js
// Generated by Haxe 4.0.0-rc.2+43ed6c9b4
(function ($global) { "use strict";
class Main {
    static main() {
        console.log("source/Main.hx:3:","Hello World");
    }
}
Main.main();
})({});

//# sourceMappingURL=run.js.map
```

Further ES6 support is planned:

- [ES6 types](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/4552)
- [ES6 module exports](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/8033)
- [Code Splitting](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/5831)